# Can a laser damage an optical disc?

Tags: optical-drive, optical-media

I have an optical BD drive writer (Pioneer 209DBK) that has its open mechanism possibly compromised, since when I press the eject button or right click and eject from Explorer, sometimes it opens normally, sometimes it half opens and closes back before I have the chance to insert or remove the disc and I get **An error occurred while ejecting the drive**.

First is my assumption correct about the mechanism and what can be done to "grease" the mechanism without compromising it?
Can that half opening harm a blu ray disc in a way similar to HDD **head crash** since the yellow light is blinking during that phase meaning a laser is being used against the disc.

Comment: I think the disc should be fine, but I suggest you replace the drive. They should not be lubricated as that collects dust and can cause additional damage.

Comment: Usually it takes 4 times to open if it was closed for more than 5 minutes, it opens normally if less. Replacing it is hard since there is no such drives in the place where I live and I am waiting if/when a new technology will emerge.

Comment: You can find them on eBay if that helps (I did look)

Comment: Sorry, I am not in the USA and eBay does not deliver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The laser will not harm the disc.  The laser used for reading optical discs are not capable of damaging optical media.  Even the lasers designed to write to optical media are designed only to affect *writable* media, not standard pressed discs.

As for the drive, it *may* be fixable.  Generally optical drives can be opened.  Its possible that debris has gotten in the gears.  If it a broken tooth from a gear, it might still work after cleaning it.  It is not likely grease, as the grease they use should last decades, but if everything looks good otherwise, clean the gears with alcohol and use a small amount of silicone grease on the gears.

Side note, optical discs like CDs, DVDs, and Blu-rays are spelled "disc," as to differentiate them from standard hard disks (and now SSDs).

Comment: The 209DBK has write capabilities that's pretty much why I use it, I edited the question.